# Resampling and merge dataset

Tags: r, merge, resampling

Consider the following dataset:

```
d1 <- c(2, 3, 8)
d2 <- data.frame(d1)
d1 <- c(1, 7, 9, 10)
d3 <- data.frame(d1)
```

Now I want to randomly draw 3 observations (without replacement) from `d3` 3 times, and each time I want to merge it with `d2`. So I should have three merged data frames with 6 observations.

I have tried with:

```
for (r in 1:3)
{
  sam <- sample(1:4, 3, replace = FALSE)

  merge <- rbind(d2, d3[sam])
}
```

But this does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `d3[sam]` will select columns. You want to use `d3[sam, ]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now I just get one data frame with 4 observation. I want 3 merged data frames with 6 observations in each, where 3 of the observations are from `d2` and 3 of the observations are randomly drawn from `d3`.

Comment: `replicate(3, rbind(d2, d3[sample(seq_len(nrow(d3)), 3), , drop=FALSE]), simplify = FALSE)` would be an option

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect :-)

Comment: One quick question: Is it possible that it also can create a data.frame (or more precisely a list), where there is three data frame with only the three random observation from `d3`. So I will have that three merged data frame with 6 observation (like you code do), but I will also have 3 data frame with the 3 observation which was choosen in merged data frame. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 <- data.frame(d1=c(2, 3, 8))
d2 <- data.frame(d1=c(1, 7, 9, 10))
1:3 %>% 
  map(~sample_n(d2, 3) %>% 
      bind_cols(d1))
[[1]]
  d1 d11
1  1   2
2  7   3
3  9   8

[[2]]
  d1 d11
1 10   2
2  1   3
3  7   8

[[3]]
  d1 d11
1  9   2
2  7   3
3 10   8
```